# JS: How can I extract a substring after a specific word and a certain number of characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery

let's say I have a URL like:

> http://randomsite.com/search?book=1234&chapter=567&pages=0177

Where page count is always four digits, but the book or chapter numbers are ambiguous.

---

What I want to do is, sometimes from a search, random extra junk might be added after a page query, like session= or referrer= or more. But, I want to cut everything off, no matter what it is, after the string "pages=####".

How would I go about doing that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `indexOf` and `substring`:

```js
const str = "http://randomsite.com/search?book=1234&chapter=567&pages=0177&randomjunk"

const strippedStr = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("pages=") + "pages=".length + 4) // always four digits

console.log(strippedStr)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast reply! It worked great! If it's possible, could you explain the logic a bit for learning purposes?

Comment: Sure! `substring` extracts the first (0) index of the string up to the position calculated by taking the index of "pages=" (`indexOf` returns the index of the start of the search string (the "p" in "pages"), so we need to add the length of "pages=" to the index to get to the end of the search string) and adding 4 for the four digits following.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the understanding. I understand it. Weirdly enough, I'm trying it with another link, and now it's leaving a single trailing character at the end because it was a symbol (really strange, I know). It must've messed with the whole making substring from the back. Is there any alternative means that fully truncates after the page number? I can use regex if that's the only way to do something like that

Comment: Okay, somebody else helped me out with this: str.match(".+&pages=[0-9]+")[0];